# Grandfather Paradox and Causal Loop

Tags: logic, metaphysics, time, paradox

How does the grandfather paradox cause a causal loop (and therefore a bootstrap paradox)?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_paradox

Comment: Hi - Can you elaborate on this question, please ? It's very briefly worded.

Answer (score 3):

**It doesn't**.

The *Grandfather Paradox* indicates a situation in which the outcome of a visit to the past negates the possibility for that visit to happen in the first place.

A *causal loop* is the state of something (an object, information, or an event) existing without origin and end, as it was caused by what it will generate.

**They are mutually exclusive**: in the first situation the origin is cut off (but the end is maintained), whereas in the second situation the origin must be causing the loop.